# plotly-dash not working in Jupyterlab and plotly extension not working either

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter, plotly-dash, jupyter-lab

I am trying to display a figure created with plotly.graph_objects.Scatterpolar.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
      r=[0,1,0.1,0.5,0.8,0],
      theta=["var1","var2", "var3", "var4","var5", "var1"],
      fill=None,
      line_color = "red",
      name='ITT'
))
fig.show()
```

But when I run it I only get a white space. I am following this [guide](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/)(https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/), I try to install the extension

```
jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly@4.14.3
```

using the extension manager but I can't find it. Is there another way of installing this extension? Or another way to solve the problem of the plotly figure not displaying?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This code works fine for me in jupyter notebook. So lets first try running the following in a terminal

`pip install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets>=7.5"`

Then reopen jupyter notebooks. And try running a new cell with only the following

`pip install plotly`

then in another separate cell run only

`import plotly.graph_objects as go`

and then run the rest of the code in its own cell, given you don't get any errors.